# How to speed-up Flash on slow netbook?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, flash

I want to play flash games on my netbook, but the run very slow. any way to speed them up? maybe somehow disable video acceleration or sound/video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that might help

> Disable Flash Hardware Acceleration?
>
> Unfortunately, many people on the AMD
>   forums reported problems when they
>   enable flash hardware acceleration. By
>   default, flash hardware acceleration
>   is enabled, so you might want to
>   disable it if you have any problems
>   with flash.
>
> Right-click on a YouTube or flash
>   video and click on Settings. Uncheck
>   “Enable Hardware Acceleration”:
>
> Read more:
>   http://windows7themes.net/flash-high-cpu-load-gpuhardware-acceleration.html#ixzz1IdEPCFuS

Answer (score 3):

Apart from upgrading your hardware and/or updating to Flash 10.2, there's nothing much that can be done

Comment: I do have Flash 10.2 r152. I read on web that the newest versions are slower. so maybe downgrading is a good option?

Comment: Not sure of 10.2 is slower. Worth a shot to downgrade, but I doubt if that'll help

Comment: thx for answer, I can't upgrade hardware on the laptop. it was just not created for newage flash games, but just for surfing the net and watching movies.