# Firefox bad Flash performance

Tags: firefox, flash

I have recently switched back to Firefox from Chrome. The only problem with it is the Flash player's performance. I have a GTX 770, and I get very low framerate at 4K YouTube videos. This problem only appears in Firefox, Chrome works fine. I read somewhere Flas does not using hardware-acceleration properly in Firefox, only when you use Flash in fullscreen mode.

Does somebody has a solution for this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First step, what version of firefox and what version of flash are you using

Comment: It's a long shot, but try [this](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5834468#5834468) fix.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the firefox but the Flash. When you turn on the statistics, it shows the render and decode method. The decoding is using the hardware acceleration, but the render is not, unless I use in fullscreen mode.


Firefox version: 32.0.2, Flash version: 15.0.0.152

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed-up Flash on slow netbook?](http://superuser.com/questions/265764/how-to-speed-up-flash-on-slow-netbook)

Comment: @PaulSweatte Not even close.